# as3: mouse_move event in full screen mode and mouseLock on slow mouse movements

Tags: actionscript-3, locking, mouse, fullscreen, mousemove

With flash and AS3 it seems to be a problem with mouse move event in full screen mode and `mouseLock` activated that I don't understand how to solve.

When I enter in full screen mode with `Stage.mouseLock` property `enabled` and i make very slow movements with the mouse, the two properties to determine the location of the mouse (`MouseEvent.movementX` and `MouseEvent.movementY`) return zero (0).

A print of the event `event.toString()` returns:

```
 [MouseEvent type="mouseMove" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=0 localY=0  stageX=0 stageY=0 relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0]
```

"The mouse can be moved as far as I want always returning 0 for x and y if the mouse are moved very slow, so it's impossible to determine the movement of the mouse." (*) After a better test I've added a correction of this sentence, below in the "Note".

It's very strange because the event are fired correctly when the mouse is moved (also with slow movements), but the returning movement is 0. Seems like the movement is < 1 but are reported only integer movements, so the values are always returned 0.

I've tried also changing mouse settings of OS (Mac OSX) without success.

If you want I can give you sample code to enter in fullscreen mode and activate Stage.mouseLock properties.

Thank you for any suggestion.

---

Note:

After testing better I've found that flash player (my flash player version is 11,7,700,203) has a behavior that looks like a bug: if the current mouse movement (`movementX` and `movementY`) is equals to the previous movement, than flash return `movementX=0` and `movementY=0`. The next mouse movement will be the correct value because it will be different from zero.

Because of this, with a constant movement always in the same direction (with a very slow movement is easier to reproduce), the player show "zero values" every two events fired.

[At this link](http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2012/07/as3-quickie-mouse-lock-and-relative-mouse-coordinates/) you can test a working example (faster than code yourself an example).

If the behavior I've found is correct, than it's easy to modify the code to rectify this problem, anyway IMHO it remain a bug. I'll report it to adobe.

[At this other link](http://wonderfl.net/c/dEtx) (thank you to @nemostein) there is another working example.

I try to explain me better: if you move the cursor very slowly (i.e. to the right direction) you'll receive the output `Movement( X:1 Y:0 )` when you move the cursor enough. If you move again the cursor enough to the right you'll receive the output `Movement( X:0 Y:0 )`. If you repeat the micro movements you'll receive the movements report always with this pattern: `(x:1,y:0),(x:0,y:0),(x:1,y:0),(x:0,y:0)...` instead of `(x:1,y:0),(x:1,y:0),(x:1,y:0)...`

I think it's wrong to receive a movement like `(x:0,y:0)` and seems to me that this values are returned every time when you make a movement equals (both the x and the y) to your previous movement.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Sample code is always useful, please do consider including it. Do these problems go away if you're not in full screen or if the `mouseLock` property is not enabled?

Comment: This is my first question in stackoverflow, thank you for the suggestion. I've seen that the problem is related only to `movementX` and `movementY` properties and is not related to `mouseLock` set to false. I've added a note in my question that, I think, explains correctly the problem and proposes a solution. You can use [this link](http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2012/07/as3-quickie-mouse-lock-and-relative-mouse-coordinates/) to test my discovery.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug, but the `MouseEvent.movementX/Y` (alongside with `MouseEvent.localX/Y` and `MouseEvent.stageX/Y`) are somewhat misleading...
Although they are `Number`s, not `int`s, there is no such thing like "half pixel", so they always reports `int` values.

The precision you're looking for (e.g.: `movementX == 0.75`) can't be achieved.

I couldn't reproduce the behavior you described at the note ("current mouse movement equals to the previous") and [here is a working example](http://wonderfl.net/c/dEtx) of `Stage.mouseLock = true` and `Stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`.

Note that if you move the cursor very slowly you'll, eventually, receive an `MouseEvent.movementX/Y == 1` (when you moved the cursor enough).

Comment: Sorry for my English. In your working example I can see the same problem. As you said if you move the cursor very slowly (i.e. to the right direction) you'll receive the output `Movement( X:1 Y:0 )` when you move the cursor enough. If you move again the cursor enough to the right you'll receive the output `Movement( X:0 Y:0 )`. If you repeat the micro movements you'll receive the movements report always with this pattern: `(x:1,y:0),(x:0,y:0),(x:1,y:0),(x:0,y:0)...` instead of `(x:1,y:0),(x:1,y:0),(x:1,y:0)...`

Comment: I'm not looking for a movement with a not integer precision (e.g.: `0.75`). I think it's correct to receive integer values, but I think it's wrong to receive a movement like `(x:0,y:0)`. This values are only returned (it seems to me) when you make a movement equals to your previous movement.  I hope this is understandable.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you in this case. I wasn't able to reproduce that "1,0,1,0" pattern. For me it is like "0,1,1,1". I've updated my working example to account for times that `MouseEvent` get dispatched.

Comment: Interesting. If you can't reproduce the problem, it may be that the behavior that I have found appears only on certain versions of the player and maybe for certain OS. Anyway, now I know the problem and I can solve in my code. Thank you for your help. Now with your new change in the example is even easier see and understand if the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked in adobe forum and they told me to open a bug.
Here is the link: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3575123